# Redirect to a specific page in ajax callback

Tags: 7, ajax, redirection

How can I redirect to a specific page in an ajax callback using Drupal 7, I've already tested this method:

```
function my_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!user_is_anonymous()) {
    return $form['my_fieldset'];
  }
  else {
    drupal_goto('login');
  }
}
```

but that code doesn't redirect to `/login` when current user is anonymous.

Comment: Do you know that the function is called. Try to call a die statement to see if it is called.

Comment: Even `die()` in an ajax callback can't be used it will generate only an ajax error popup, ajax callback should return something as I guess but using `drupal_goto()` does not return any statement, so no change will be applied while calling `drupal_goto()`, the redirection should be done differently I guess but I don't have any idea how to resolve that.

Comment: Isn't it because ajax callbacks are handled on the `system/ajax` menu route and thus issuing a `goto` won't have any effect? I would see if you could set a form state property and check that value in the form building method, if TRUE, try the goto.

Comment: Smart idea Kevin but sadly it generate an ajax error popup too, this time the source path of error is `/system/ajax`, what I did is in `my_ajax_callback()` I add `$form_state['redirect'] = TRUE;` instead of `drupal_goto()` call, and in my form builder I add `if (isset($form_state['redirect']) && $form_state['redirect']) { drupal_goto('login'); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. You should try this:

```
ctools_include('ajax'); 
ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
$commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect('login');
return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
```

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer, works like a charm. Thanks @davide-bruner.